# AVCaptureDeviceInput Initialization Fails

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, avkit

I'm trying to access the front camera on my iPhone X, however when I try to create an AVCaptureDeviceInput object, initialization fails.

```swift
let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .front)

        if let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
            if let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
```

Comment: Couldnt find much wrong with the code. Have you tested it on other devices?? Is it working there??

Comment: I don't have any other devices to test it on. I have an identical code snippet from another app that works, not sure why. This code doesn't seem to depend on any other variables

Comment: `let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .front)
        
        if let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
            if let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {`

Comment: Try setting `sessionPreset`. Maybe that works for you you can do so by using the following code: `capture_session_name.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720`.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Has your app gone through the required user authorisation? This could happen if you haven't gone through the necessary authorisation as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios). The app will automatically request authorisation to use the camera but you should also be providing usage descriptions in your info.plist...